# Visual studio export template replaces original projectname with $safeprojectname$

Tags: visual-studio-2012

My project is a mvc4 project in visual studio 2013 ultimate.
I tryd to send my project by following the steps :

File > Export template > (leave all the options as default)

I get a zip that i unpack. If i open the unpacked solution and run the program i get alot of errors. It looks like visual studio replaced all the text that contained the projectname with $safeprojectname$. How can i export the project without visual studio replacing all the 'projectname' spots so that i can run my program.

I tryed creating a new project (console application) with no code in it, if i export it and import it i get the same message first i get :

```
Warning 1   Load of property 'RootNamespace' failed.  The string for the root namespace must be a valid identifier. SvenEind
```

and after running i get

190 errors 31 warnings

I tryd importing http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/building-the-ef5-mvc4-chapter-downloads and that worked for me.

So i guess the problem is in some kind of settings for exporting files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> replaced all the text that contained the projectname with $safeprojectname$

This is very much by design.  You created a *project template*, a cookie-cutter for new projects.  You are **not** supposed to do anything with the .zip archive.  It should sit patiently in your "My Exported Templates" folder.  Until the day arrives that you want to start a new project.

You then can pick the template instead of using one of the built-in ones that were preinstalled by the Visual Studio installer.  Visual Studio prompts you for the project name.  It then unzips the archive, copying the files into your new project directory.  And modifies the files, `$safeprojectname$` is substituted by the new project name you entered.  You now have a good start for your new project, using the settings and assets that you saved earlier when you created the template.

Sounds like you had an entirely different use in mind, I can't guess at the intention from the question.

Comment: Thanks, my intentions were to send a profject which they could open by clicking the .sln file without haveing to create a new project. (short: open an existing project)

Comment: Just send them a copy of your existing solution.

Comment: is there a way to export as solution, or do i need to go to the solution in my documents folder and copy it there..

Comment: Just copy the files.  Using distributed source control, say github, is never a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm.  I got this error on Build:

```
The app manifest must be valid as per schema: Line 42, Column 18, Reason: '$safeprojectname$' violates pattern constraint of '([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*)(\.[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*)*'. The attribute 'Id' with value '$safeprojectname$' failed to parse.
```

So I grabbed the project name from the VS Configuration Manger and put it in the app manifest like this.

```
<Applications>
  <Application
    Id="CordovaApp.Windows10"
```

And the error went away and the project built.  HTH.